# Getting route path arguments in middleware

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

In Slim 3 I have group with the same actions which depends on `$args`:

```
$this->group('{id}/', function () {
    $this->get('first/', function (Request $req, Response $res, $args) {
        $myData = operations($args['id']);
        ...
    });

    $this->post('second/', function (Request $req, Response $res, $args) {
        $myData = operations($args['id']);
        ...
    });
});
```

I could transfer those common operations to higher level.
As I read it could be middleware but in middleware I cannot (or don't know how) access to `$args`.

```
->add(function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, callable $next) {
    //how to get arguments?
    $request = $request->withAttribute('myData', operations($id); 
    $response = $next($request, $response);

    return $response;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the route params with the third item of the route info attribute:

```
$routeParams = $request->getAttribute('routeInfo')[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
$route = $req->getAttribute('route');
if (! is_null($route)) {
    print_r($route->getArguments()); // ['id' => 123]
    print_r($route->getArgument('id')); // 123
}
```